# Ensure that only one record has a specific value

Tags: mysql

Let's say there's a table that stores jobs and their state (something like `CREATE TABLE jobs (id INT, status VARCHAR(255))`, how to ensure that only one job could be in `running` state i.e. how a query that tries to start a job should look like?

Comment: Which version of mysql?

Comment: Presumably, you'll need to identify and update the job you want to start *and* confirm nothing else is in a "running" state in a single query; or, build a transaction that basically locks the table down, confirms nothing is running, and then marks the next job as running. I suppose having a column that either holds the `id` value converted to a string or holds `running` (with a unique constraint on it) could do the trick, but it's probably overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this query does the trick (extra nesting because of MySQL weirdness)

```
UPDATE jobs
SET state = 'running'
WHERE id = 1 AND NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1
 FROM (SELECT 1 FROM jobs WHERE state = 'running') AS n
)
```

Answer (score 0):

That can't be performed with single query. Therefore you have to create stored routine like that:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `start_job`( IN `pid` INT, IN `state` varchar )
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN
   UPDATE * 
     FROM jobs AS w
      SET w.status = "idle"
    WHERE w.status = "running"
   ;
   INSERT INTO jobs (id, status)
   VALUES (pid, state)
       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
          status = state
   ;
END
```